# Fastest way to generate data using pyspark (on aws glue)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to use AWS GLUE with pyspark to generate fake data using the Python Faker library. I'm not very familiar with pyspark, and I'd like to find the fastest way to generate fake data (up to around 10 tb). In particular, the row based generation I'm using at the moment takes about 15 minutes to generate 1.5 gb:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

from pyspark.sql import Row
from faker import Faker 

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# number of records
num_records = int(1e6)

# faker settings
fake = Faker('nl_NL')
fake_line = lambda x: Row(fake.sha256(), fake.name(), fake.street_name(), fake.province(), fake.country(), fake.phone_number(), fake.email(), fake.iban())
df_header = ['sha256', 'name', 'streetname', 'province', 'country', 'phonenumber', 'email', 'iban']

# create 
df = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_records)).map(fake_line).toDF(schema = df_header)
dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, 'dynamic_faker')

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame = dynamic_df,
connection_type = "s3",
connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket-path"},
format = "csv",
transformation_ctx = "")

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your output format from `csv` to `parquet`, the performance should be improved quite a lot. Since your fake data is huge, you might not want to download it and read it, so it's OK if it's not human - readable.

Another option is to increase your numbers of `DPU` on Glue, so it can process more data in each time unit.